# How to modify the javascript code with AST using babel?

Tags: javascript, babeljs, abstract-syntax-tree

I've a javascript function like this

```
function testFunction(datamap){
    if(datamap.has("key")){

        console.log(datamap.get('key'));
    }
    else{
        console.log("Key is not present")
    }

    console.log("Hi This  is check statement.");


    let key2=datamap.get('key2');
}
```

datamap is a parameter of type Map.

I want to convert the above function to like below

```
function testFunction(datamap){
 
   if(datamap.has("key")){

        if(!datamap.has('key')){
        console.log('key is not present in datamap')
         }
    }
    
// console.log("Hi This  is check statement.");-- This statement is deleted
    if(!datamap.has("key2")){ //Get statement is converted to check
       console.log('key2 is not present in datamap')
    }
}
```

I want to replace all statements apart from the IfSTATEMENT with dataMap.has callExpression and datamap.get with empty strings. and I want to add a check whereever datamap.get is used

I've read about AST and transforming the AST with babel but I could not figure out how to write this in visitor pattern.
I've tried something in astexplorer but was no way near what I wanted.

Idea is that we transform the function in a way that we add a check if the key is supposed to be present in the datamap instead of nullpointer or undifined wherever the value from datamap.get is accessed

My aim is to instrument the function and then if I run the instrumented function with a Map with some keys , It should give me the info of what keys are missing in the provided datamap argument

Could someone provide any insight on how this could be done? or can this be done without instrumenting the function just by traversing the AST?

Comment: erm, so you never want to `console.log('key is not present in datamap')` ??? since if the datamap has the key, it certainly does not not have the key

Comment: @Bravo, Basically the idea is that we transform the function in a way that we add a check if the key is supposed to be present in the datamap instead of nullpointer or undifined wherever the value from datamap.get is accessed

Comment: @Bravo My aim is to instrument the function and then if I run the instrumented function with a Map with some keys , It should give me the info of what keys are missing in the provided datamap argument